# example of non-quasi-greedy basis

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

The following is an example of non-quasi-greedy basis which i can't understand it.
Consider the sequence space $X$
=$\{(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty:\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
converges$\}$ endowed with the norm $\|(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\| =
max_N|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n|.$ The unit vector basis
$(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of $X$ is isometrically equivalent to the
summing basis in $c_0.$ Pick $x=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in X$ given by
$$x=(1,-1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4},...,\frac{1}{k},-\frac{1}{k^2},...,-\frac{1}{k^2},...).$$
so that each $1/n$ is followed by $n$ terms $-1/n^2$
 This vector consists of blocks of length $k+1,$ and the sum of
the coordinates in each block is zero. For $j \in \mathbb{N},$ pick
$\epsilon \in (1/(j^2+1), 1/j^2).$ We have $$\|T_\epsilon(x)\| \geqq
\displaystyle\sum_{\{n:|a_n|>\epsilon\}}a_n=\sum_{n=j+1}^{j^2}\frac{1}{n}
\geqq \int_{j+1}^{j^2+1}\frac{1}{x}dx = ln\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}$$ which
combined with $T_\epsilon(x) = G_{m_\epsilon}(x)$ and
$G_m(x)=T_{\epsilon_m}(x)$ gives $\displaystyle
\sup_n\|\mathcal{G}_n(x)\|=\infty$ where $T_\epsilon(x)$ is the thresholding operator and $G_m(x)$ is the greedy sum as the following note shows. Hence
$(\mathcal{G}_n(x))_{n=1}^\infty$ does not converge.

Any help in understanding the example will be appreiated.

Note:
Strictly greedy sums and thresholding operators are closely
related. To every $x \in X$ there corresponds a subset of integers
$$\mathbb{N}_x=\{m \in \mathbb{N}:\text{there is a stritly greedy sum of }x \text{ of order } m\}.$$
Then for $\epsilon > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_x,$ we have
$$T_\epsilon(x)=G_{m_\epsilon}(x)\ \text{and}\  G_m(x)=T_{\epsilon_m}(x),$$
where $$m_\epsilon=|\{n \in \mathbb{N}:|e_n^*(x)|>\epsilon|\}|
\text{ and } \displaystyle \max_{n \notin A_m(x)} |e_n^*(x)|\leq
\epsilon_m < \displaystyle\min_{n \in A_m(x)}|e_n^*(x)|$$